# Unable to get chrome driver working through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, jenkins-plugins, xvfb, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to get chrome driver working via Jenkins. My tests run fine from a terminal window but I wish to run them from Jenkins in headless mode.

I have the latest recommended version of chrome driver installed and Chrome version 28.0.1500.71. Chromedriver has been placed on my path at /Usr/bin.

However when I attempt to run the tests from Jenkins I get an error message:

```
 "Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using chrome binary at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError)"
```

I have also tried installing previous version of chrome and chromedriver but I get the same error message.

So after some investigation I found that in order to run headless tests via Jenkins you may need to have installed xvfb. (i say may because I am not 100% sure if this is correct) So I installed xvfb via Xquartz and the xvfb file is also on my path at /Usr/bin.

However even after doing the above with Xvfs I still get the error. Xvfs appears to start successfully as I get the message: Xvfb starting$ /Usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 -fbdir /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/2013-07-15_16-24-193595155347701391882xvfb in the console output in Jenkins.

Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong? I am new to the world of Macs so there may be something I am missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Managed to get this sorted. Instead of enabling Xvfb in the job configuration build environment section, I ran it using a terminal command and it now works. So my terminal command is now: xvfb-run cucumber --tags @automated  - So this issue can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this sorted. Instead of enabling Xvfb in the job configuration build environment section, I ran it using a terminal command and it now works. So my terminal command is now: xvfb-run cucumber --tags @automated - So this issue can be closed